# How to query view from Tableau based on multiple value filter using Python urllib.parse.urlencode function?

Tags: python, tableau-api, urlencode

I am trying to create a PDF from a Tableau Dashboard, and I want to do that using Python. I am using the below Python function to create the URL required to query the Dashboard.

```py
URL = base_end_point + urllib.parse.urlencode(filters, doseq=True)
```

Where filters are the dictionary that has keys = filter names, and values that represent the values for these filters.

An example of the dictionary filters is shown below

```py
filters  =  ex: {'vf_Dealer': 'ABC', 'vf_Customer': 'Steve', 'vf_Items': ['Milk', 'Bread', 'Soap']}
```

Notice that I have multiple items in the 'vf_Items'. The problem is that the above method only returns the report for the first item, in this case, "Milk"